# Specificity in ancient depictions of Olympus?

Tags: homer, the-iliad, the-odyssey

The highest peak in Greece is Mount Olympus, near the northwestern Aegean coast. Was this taken as the literal home of the Olympian gods by worshipful ancient Greeks, or was it merely figurative to speak as though the gods resided on Olympus? **Do any ancient Greek texts give very specific details when depicting Olympus?** For example, are the buildings in 'heaven' supposed to rest on clouds or earth? I just reread the *Iliad* and the *Odyssey*, and unless I read something too cursorily, Homer's always rather vague about these matters. (But my question is about all extant ancient Greek texts, not just Homer.)

Comment: Related: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1592/53

Comment: This question wrt the historical *realities* of myth is too complex for a succinct answer here. Revert to Martin Nilsson's *A History of Greek Religion* for a comprehensive review. https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Greek_Religion/mOAoAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: Hesiod talks about the Muses living a litle bit below the main peak, but that's  as specific as it gets in his account of the geography